# are web2py Database Abstraction Layer (DAL) references on cascade by default?

Tags: python, web2py, database-abstraction

When I create a database in web2py using the DAL, and I create a table for the user comments on my website for example and I need to be able to get the user that sent that particular comment, I can do it by email..
However emails can change over time (possible option) and the database itself could end up looking for a non existent user if the email is not updated on all "child" tables that uses that email as reference 1 to 1 for that user.
For this reasons, I would need to automatically update all the Foreign Keys in child tables, so is this feature (update on cascade on foreign keys) present and by default when using DAL / is it possible to tell the DAL connection to do it by adding a `updateoncascade=True` in needed `Field("name", type="type", notnull=True, updateoncascade=True)` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAL does not provide an API to specify `ON UPDATE CASCADE` when creating a table, so you would have to do that externally. Alternatively, you could make use of the [`_after_update` hook](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#callbacks-on-record-insert-delete-and-update) to update records in any child tables.

Also consider whether you want to set a foreign key on the email address rather than using the built-in `reference` field functionality, which creates a foreign key on the `id` field of the parent table. Because the `id` of a given user record will never change, you do not have to worry about cascading updates:

```
db.define_table('comments',
    ...,
    Field('author', 'reference auth_user'))
```

Above, `'reference auth_user'` sets up a foreign key to the `db.auth_user.id` field.

Comment: This means that I don't have to update anything but the email on the users table because everything on the "child" tables is related on the id that is generated automatically in the `define table` if I get it correctly, right?